# Is there any order in $match or filter query in Monogodb for performance issues

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

Let's have some big data in mongodb, for example 100 million documents.
I have a simple and a very complicated filter queries.

```
const simpleQuery = {x: "a"}
const complicatedQuery = { // Some interesting expressions }
```

I expected only simple query can decrease result from 100 million to for example 10. I don't want to consume cpu with the complicated query in 100 million documents because 10 documents is enough, so in an aggregate operation:

Are two consequent match queries make sense?

```
{
    $match: simpleQuery
},
{
    $match: complicatedQuery
}
```

Or, ordering in one match is enough?

```
{
    $match: {...simpleQuery, ...complicatedQuery}
},
```

Or, is there another smart way? Also, is the same answer valid in find/findOne operations?

I can't find any document about the situation. Thanks!

Comment: Having consecutive `$match` operations is same  as -> having single `$match` operation with all the filters specified together. In fact, the query optimizer combines the the two `$match` stages, in case you have two consecutive `$match` stages. See https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline-optimization/#-match----match-coalescence